# CSV Writer won't quote all fields

Tags: python, csv

Hey so i have a tkinter GUI in which inputs from a user are saved into a CSV file. However when inputs are saved to the csv file, the csv writer only puts quotes in the beginning and ending of a line. How do i make it so that double quotes are put around every value.

```
def get_data():
    global button
    Message_data = Message.get()
    if len(Message_data) > 140:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", 'Error: Het bericht mag maximaal 140 tekens bevatten')
        return
    Name_data = Name.get()
    if Message_data == '' and Name_data == '':
        return
    Today = datetime.datetime.today()
    s = Today.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M")
    stations = ['Arnhem', 'Almere', 'Amersfoort', 'Almelo', 'Alkmaar', 'Apeldoorn', 'Assen', 'Amsterdam', 'Boxtel',
                'Breda', 'Dordrecht', 'Delft', 'Deventer', 'Enschede', 'Gouda', 'Groningen', 'Den Haag', 'Hengelo',
                'Haarlem', 'Helmond', 'Hoorn', 'Heerlen', 'Den Bosch', 'Hilversum', 'Leiden', 'Lelystad', 'Leeuwarden',
                'Maastricht', 'Nijmegen', 'Oss', 'Roermond', 'Roosendaal', 'Sittard', 'Tilburg', 'Utrecht', 'Venlo',
                'Vlissingen', 'Zaandam', 'Zwolle', 'Zutphen']
    station = random.choice(stations)
    with open('berichten.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        if Name_data == '':
            w.writerow([Message_data + ", " + s + ", " + 'anoniem' + ", " + station])
        else:
            w.writerow([Message_data + ", " + s + ", " + Name_data + ", " + station])
```

I tried changing the quoting to csv.QUOTE_MINIMUM but no luck

Comment: How do you want the resulting csv file to look like? I'm asking because you seem to be creating a big string (message data, concatenated with a comma, then another string `s`, then `'anoniem'`... and so on) and putting that into a single column. So the CSV writer is quoting one (and only one) string. Don't you want more than one column in your csv? Because I suspect you want something like `w.writerow([Message_data, s, 'anoniem', station])` (notice that's a list with 4 items in it, not a list with 1 item in it like you have in your current code)

Comment: I managed to solve it by chaning the w.writerow command to this: 
w.writerow([Message_data, s, 'anoniem', station])